# jenkins perform operations after build failed

Tags: build, jenkins

I would like to process some operations only if the build failed. For example, if runtime execution has thrown a core dump (it doesn't happen always, of course) and I want to move it somewhere, so that the next day build won't remove it.

Does anyone know how to perform anything in case a build fails?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin). With this you can use `hudson` api's to check if the build is a failure or not, and then do the required actions using groovy script. For example, you can use following script to check if the build is unstable or better

```
if(manager.build.result.isBetterOrEqualTo(hudson.model.Result.UNSTABLE))
{
 \\ do something
}
```

Comment: involving another language in your build process is often a bad idea... unless it is necessary, not just "well I know how to do this in `ruby`"

Answer (score 0):

Well if it is set up to log to std out, it will be in the Jenkins log, if not, can you set it up to log to a file in you workspace , then you can package as an artifact based on the name... If you are running in a posix system you can redirect stderr to stdout and direct those both to a file in your run command. Or pipe them through tee, so you get them in both

Comment: let's say, I've got a sequence of instructions I call in shell one by one. If any of them fails, I'd like to run "mv file dir". Logging to stdout/stderr doesn't make any difference for me.

Comment: well you can check the return values of the commands in the script or you can check $? after they are executed